# Is following macro works properly?

Tags: c, linux, macros, ternary-operator

I'm having following macro

```
#define GET_COUNT(model,hdr)  ((model == NEW) ? \
                              ((hdr)->val.count > 3 ? \
                              ((hdr)->val.count = 3) | (hdr)->val.count : \
                              (hdr)->val.count) :     \
                              (hdr)->val.count > 4 ?  \
                              ((hdr)->val.count = 4) | (hdr)->val.count : \
                               (hdr)->val.count)
```

Above macro should work as follows

First it need to check for the model, if model is NEW it should check for count if `count > 3` it should assign count as 3 and it return count else return count value as is. If model not equal to NEW, it should check for `count > 4`, if `count > 4` it should assign count = 4 and return count else return count value as is.

Is above macro works as my expectation or do i need to change any thing?

My main concern is  after assigning a value i'm using | operator to return count value is this works?

Comment: Why are you even using a macro for this ? It should be a function, and it should be written more clearly.

Comment: Why don't you write a sample program with this macro & pass some valid inputs & test the output?

Comment: Why even bother writing `((hdr)->val.count = 3) | (hdr)->val.count`. The C standard specifies that an assignment evaluates to the value of the left hand operand **after** the assignment, ie: `(hdr)->val.count = 3` evaluates to 3...

Comment: @anishsane not a good way of testing out undefined behaviour :)

Comment: ^^ I agree, but I guess, it's a very tiny code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate the ternary operator `a ? b : c` to

```
if (a) {
    return b;
} else {
    return c;
}
```

Applied to your macro, you get

```
? GET_COUNT(? model, ? hdr)
{
    if (model == NEW) {
        if (hdr->val.count > 3) {
            return (hdr->val.count = 3) | hdr->val.count;
        else
            return hdr->val.count;
    } else {
        if (hdr->val.count > 4)
            return (hdr->val.count = 4) | hdr->val.count;
        else
            return hdr->val.count;
    }
}
```

In every branch, `GET_COUNT` returns `hdr->val.count`. Therefore, you can refactor this to

```
? GET_COUNT(? model, ? hdr)
{
    if (model == NEW) {
        if (hdr->val.count > 3) {
            hdr->val.count = 3;
    } else {
        if (hdr->val.count > 4)
            hdr->val.count = 4;
    }

    return hdr->val.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in this macro causes undefined behaviour. In the expression

```
((hdr)->val.count = 3) | (hdr)->val.count
```

you write the variable but also read it separately, without an intervening sequence point.

It's not exactly clear to me what your intention was in writing this expression, but this is all vastly inferior to using a function.

```
inline T check_max(T *value, T the_max)
{
    if ( *value > the_max )
        *value = the_max;

    return *value;
}

inline T get_count(MODEL model, HDR *hdr)
{
     return check_max(&hdr->val.count, model == MODEL_NEW ? 3 : 4);
}
```